# my additional include directory for openSSL isn't recognized

Tags: c++, visual-studio, openssl, include, include-path

I'm trying to use openSSL on a c++ application on VS2015.
I downloaded the OpenSSL Win32 binaries.

I have a directory with an "Include" and "Lib" subdirectory.
The "Include" subdirectory contains right the "OpenSSL" folder.

I was going in the property of my project ( x86) under " Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories" and i added the full directory:

```
C:\OpenSSL-Win32\include
```

Then i added under "Project Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories" i added the "Lib" subfolder, then i was on "Project Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies" and add these two lines:

```
libeay32.lib 
ssleay32.lib
```

When i'm trying to do:

```
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
```

> the "openssl" directory is not found.

I really verify all the path, all appear to be ok but i didn't work.

Comment: Very interesting.. If I were you, (1)check everything is doing same config.(I mean build is debug but include path setting is release.. etc)  (2)move openssl folder and test

Comment: Please provide some of your build log.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by setting the library/include path in "All Configuration" instead of x86/x64.

Problem solved.

Thanks.